# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... nodejs-question

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemon

I started to learn nodejs and I try to start a server connect to mongodb and have the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXWa5.png)

and here my server.js file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiKDi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read your console output carefully as it clearly states what is the problem.
[image]

`useCreateIndex` and `useFindModify` are no longer supported in mongoose.

Just remove them from your connection options.